# How to get a pending filter only for a contract

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

I would like to do the equivalent of:

> pendingEvent = web3.eth.filter('pending');

but only for a specific contract:

> pendingContractEvent = myContractInstance.allEvents('pending');

or more specifically:

> pendingContractEvent = myContractInstance.myEvent('pending');

When I do this, I get the event only when the transaction is included in a block (like 'latest').

Comment: Hope you solved issue, mark ans  as resolved. So that it will help community to find ans very easy.

Comment: how to do this on web3py? on Python

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to do the equivalent of:
>
> pendingEvent = web3.eth.filter('pending');

Yes you can do using web3.eth.filter with options. By specifying address in options you can do archive your problem. I am just attaching sample code for ref.

```
var options = {address: <CONTRACTADDRESS>};
var filter = web3.eth.filter('pending', options);

filter.watch('pending',function (error, log) {
     console.log(log);
  }
});
```

Click below link for more details.

https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API

Comment: Does not seem to work: I only have 7 tx on my contract and this filter sends me all pending tx. I have web3 version ^0.19.0

Comment: If you're not providing contract I'd then you will get all pending trans